# Mapping a Reflexive Many-to-Many relationship with NHibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to use NHibernate with an existing database. The database records unidirectional relationships between users:

```
Users
    UserId              PK
    Name

Relationships
    RelationshipId      PK
    ParentId            FK:Users_UserId
    ChildId             FK:Users_UserId
```

I want to represent this using NHibernate. At the moment, I have the following POCO object:

```
class User {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> ParentUsers {get; set;}
    public ICollection<User> ChildUsers {get; set;}
}
```

I also have this mapping file:

```
<class name="User" table="Users">
    <id name="Id"></id>
    <property name="Name"></property>
</class>
```

I've looked at guides on the web, but I can't work out what I need to put in the mapping file to wire up my two `ICollection` properties.

How should I map this data structure? Is my current approach correct, or is it better to create a second POCO class, and just use two `many-to-one` relationships?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm probably missing something, but this should get you started:

```
<idbag name="ParentUsers" table="Relationships">
  <collection-id column="RelationshipId" type="...">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </collection-id>
  <key column="ChildId"/>
  <many-to-many column="ParentId" class="User"/>
</idbag>
<idbag name="ChildUsers" table="Relationships">
  <collection-id column="RelationshipId" type="...">
    <generator class="..."/>
  </collection-id>
  <key column="ParentId"/>
  <many-to-many column="ChildId" class="User"/>
</idbag>
```

Also, one of the collections should be marked as `inverse`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this works fine. It's kind of hard to find concrete examples for mapping definitions on the web.